# Wrapping titles don't line up on the left correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Noticed on questions with titles that wrap over to the next line (e.g. [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19209/how-do-i-fix-the-error-expression-must-evaluate-to-a-node-set-setting-web-confi)) that the spacing doesn't line up correctly on the left:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deployment.